# Yii CGridView, displaying multiple columns from related model with filtering capability

Tags: php, yii, cgridview, yii-relations

I'm pretty new to yii and I bumped into the following problem. I have 2 related tables, **ClientTicket** and **Product** with the following structure:

### ClientTicket

- id
- ticket_name
- client_id
- product_id

### Product

- id
- type
- model
- brand

The two tables are related through a foreign key which binds ClientTicket.product_id to Product.id.

### The Problem

In the admin view of the ClientTicket I've managed to include two of the Product columns (brand, model) and have the search box display for each of them, but the filtering isn't working as expected. Ex: When I search in either of the two search boxes(brand, model), the other one populates automatically with the same value I typed (so no search results).

### The ClientTicket model:

```
    public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'product' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Product', 'product_id'),
        ........
    );
}

    public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    ...
    $criteria->compare('product.model',$this->product_id, true);
    $criteria->compare('product.brand',$this->product_id, true);
    ...

    $criteria->with=array(..., 'product',);
    $criteria->together= true;

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 10),
    ));
}
```

### The ClientTicket Admin view file:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'client-ticket-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'ticket_number',
    'ticket_date',
    array('name'=>'agent_id',
        'header'=> 'Agent',
        'value'=> '$data->ticket_agent->name',
        'filter'=>CHtml::listData(Agent::model()->findAll(), 'name', 'name'),
        ),
    ...
    array('name'=>'product_id',
        'header'=> 'Product',
        'value'=> '$data->product->model',
        ),
    array('name'=>'product_id',
        'header'=> 'Brand',
        'value'=>'$data->product->brand'
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `product`and `brand` columns both have the same `name` but different `values`. The filter obtains the field name from `name` unless you explicitly state it i.e create your own active field. In addition you are using the same attribute `product_id` to search both fields in your `search` function.

How to filter using related models has been answered at [Yii - how can I search by a column from foreign/related key on admin page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320592/yii-how-can-i-search-by-a-column-from-foreign-related-key-on-admin-page/15320828#15320828)

Comment: how should @Raven_ 007 change the array?

Answer (score 0):

For other users reference, here's how i got it to work. 
Again, Thank you **topher** for the prompt response. :)

### Inside ClientTicket model:

- declared a new public variable named $brand
- added ***'brand'*** to ***'safe'***  ***'on'=>'search'*** array, inside of ***rules()*** function
- added a new criteria inside the ***search()*** function like so:
  **$criteria->compare('product.brand',$this->brand, true);**

### In the ClientTicket admin view file:

modified the product brand column from this:

```
array('name'=>'product_id',
    'header'=> 'Brand',
    'value'=>'$data->product->brand'
    ),
```

to this:

```
 array('name'=>'product.brand',
    'header'=> 'Brand',
    'filter'=>CHtml::activeTextField($model,'brand'),
    ),
```